# How to put video time stamp for long videos in moment js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a video whose duration is `3632.065306` secs which is `1:00:32` 1 hour and 32 secs in normal time

My issues here are

1. when I run the code below I get only 36 secs, how can i see `1:00:32`
2. It should show the hour only when the input > 59 mins and 59 secs, that is if input = `52.209` then the output should be  `00:52` 52 secs.

```js
const rawVideoDuration = 3632.065306;
const output = moment(rawVideoDuration , 'ss.SSS', 'en').format('HH:mm:ss');
console.log('output', output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually this feature seems to be not implemented at all.
[Duration missing features](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/463)
, but you can do this:

**Answer question 1:**

multiply your rawVideoDuration * 1000 to get milliseconds and use this notation:

```js
const rawVideoDuration = 3632.065306;
const output = moment.utc(rawVideoDuration * 1000).format('HH:mm:ss');
console.log('output', output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

**Answer question 2:**

make the format conditional based (and maybe wrap all into a function)

```js
const rawVideoDuration = 3632.065306;
const durationMilliseconds = rawVideoDuration * 1000;

let output;
if (durationMilliseconds < 3600000) {
  output = moment.utc(durationMilliseconds).format("mm:ss");
} else {
  output = moment.utc(durationMilliseconds).format("HH:mm:ss");
}

console.log('output', output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```